# Why can't I assign matrix_exp from dlib to std::vector?

Tags: c++, dlib

I am using Dlib thanks to its great matrix sub module. I find it very complete and useful to do fast scientific algorithm. I managed to add some custom operations and get the overall idea how it works.

However, there is a question that bother me since quite some time. Is there specific reason why it seems impossible to assign any kind of matrix expression to an `std::vector` ?

EDIT:

Here is a typical dlib function:

```
template <typename EXP>
const matrix_op<op_trans<EXP> > trans(const matrix_exp<EXP>& m) {
  typedef op_trans<EXP> op;
  return matrix_op<op>(op(m.ref());
}
```

And if I want to implement the corresponding function that takes and returns `std::vector` instead, I think I would do:

```
template <typename EXP>
const std::vector<matrix_op<op_trans<EXP> > > trans(const std::vector<matrix_exp<EXP> >& ms) {
  std::vector<matrix_op<op_trans<EXP> > > out(ms.size());
  typedef op_resize_bilinear<EXP> op;
  for (int i = 0; i < ms.size(); ++i)
    out[i] = matrix_op<op>(op(ms.ref()));
  return out;
}
```

But as it works, any expression is seen as `matrix_exp` being `matrix`, `matrix_op`, `matrix_add_exp`... But this is not true with `std::vector<matrix_exp>`:

`‘const std::vector<smu::matrix<float> >’ is not derived from ‘const std::vector<smu::matrix_exp<EXP> >’`

I just want to know if this is intentional from dlib, if there are any reason for it as it could be useful in several algorithms that need to process several matrices at once... and if some work around this could work

Comment: _"seems impossible to assign any kind of matrix expression to an std::vector"_: please give details. See _"How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"_:   http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You'd have to ask the library maintainers why they did implement this feature?

Comment: Yeah it's more why they didn't get this feature in the library itself. I don't see any big issue myself but I'm new to the template expression technique so if there were huge reasons for that, I just wanted to know and I didn't find similar question on internet...

Comment: @baptiste -- The answer given by DevSolar shows that the authors were wise.  What if you want to store the matrix in some other sequence container, such as `std::deque` or `std::list`, etc.?  Using the iterator paradigm, it is possible to store dlib::matrix in these other containers, not just `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: First time I am looking at dlib, I'm taking a shot in the dark here and have no idea how dlib / its matrix class actually work.)

A `dlib::matrix` [has member functions including `begin()` and `end()`](http://dlib.net/dlib/matrix/matrix_abstract.h.html#matrix), which will...

> ...iterate over the elements of the matrix in row major order if layout is row_major_layout or in column major order if layout is column_major_layout.

Assigning to a `std::vector` can thus be done pretty straightforward:

```
 dlib::matrix< ... > mat;
 // fill the matrix, do operations on it etc.    
 std::vector< mat::type > vec( mat.begin(), mat.end() );
```

Whether that is what you are looking for, I don't know, because you did not really tell us. ;-)

Comment: I just saw that you were asking about `matrix_exp`, not `matrix`. As most well-behaved C++ data containers, that noteable also has `begin()` and `end()`, which will *"...iterate over the elements of the matrix in row major order."*